# Syntax error on token "boolean", invalid Expression

Tags: java, android, adt

-I am encountering "Syntax error on token "boolean", invalid Expression" error in if/else part or the code below . Am getting this error 3 times on all "else/if" lines.

-Another error I am getting is on the last "else" that i have to insert a ";" after the statement which is not resolving anything.

```
package com.dey2929.bmihealth;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
TextView result;
TextView review;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvmybmi);
    review = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.review);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String YourBmi = intent.getStringExtra("YourBmi");
     result.setText(" Your BMI is: " + YourBmi);
      if (boolean.valueof(YourBmi) <= 18.0)
      {
          review.setText("You are Underweight ");

      }
      else if ((boolean.valueof(YourBmi) > 18.0 && boolean.valueof(YourBmi) < 25.0 ))
      {
          review.setText("You are Normal (healthy weight) ");
      }
      else ((boolean.valueof(YourBmi)) > 25.0)
      {
          review.setText("You are Overweight");
      }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.result, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

UPDATE:

EDIT- Error only in the last else line is left i.e.

> - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
>     -Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
>
>   - Insert assignment operator expression to complete assignment.

modified code :

```
package com.dey2929.bmihealth;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
TextView result;
TextView review;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvmybmi);
    review = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.review);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String YourBmi = intent.getStringExtra("YourBmi");
     result.setText(" Your BMI is: " + YourBmi);
      if (Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) <= 18.0)
      {
          review.setText("You are Underweight ");

      }
      else if ((Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) > 18.0 && Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) < 25.0 ))
      {
          review.setText("You are Normal (healthy weight) ");
      }
      else (Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) > 25.0)
      {
          review.setText("You are Overweight");
      }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.result, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: `boolean.valueof(YourBmi)` What is that ? May are you looking for `Double.valueOf(bmi) <= 18.0`

Comment: I put my answer bellow. You have to put else if in last else.

Comment: I said chage you last else lite from else to else if. I wrote it in my  answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your "YourBmi" has a double value, make this changes:

**EDITED:** I changed the else if code. It has to much parenthesis and add another if in last alse.

```
  if (Double.valueOf(YourBmi) <= 18.0)
  {
      review.setText("You are Underweight ");

  }
  else if (Double.valueOf(YourBmi) > 18.0 && Double.valueOf(YourBmi) < 25.0 )
  {
      review.setText("You are Normal (healthy weight) ");
  }
  else if(Double.valueOf(YourBmi) > 25.0)
  {
      review.setText("You are Overweight");
  }
```

Comment: error when i tried this was in the line `else if(Double.valueOf(YourBmi) > 25.0)
  {`
errors :
-The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
-Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment

Comment: Try to clear your code. Project->Clear->Your Project.                In my code its working.

Answer (score 5):

following is invalid

```
  if (boolean.valueof(YourBmi) <= 18.0)
```

change it to

```
  if (Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) <= 18.0)
```

I assume `YourBmi` would contain floating number in `String` form

Comment: it is a boolean converted to string which i am converting to boolean again to compare.

Comment: how do you convert a boolean (true/false) with greater or equals to 18.0 number ?

Comment: Error on above two lines is resolved. 
Only last line is giving error:
 else ((Float.parsefloat(YourBmi)) > 25.0)

Comment: it is `parseFloat` , also read the javadoc you would have better idea

Comment: @user3116603 Why don't you pass directly a float value through your intent ?

Comment: @ZouZou I am new to android development. This is my first application and my first java code aswell. So am not aware of many alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

`boolean` is not a class, you cannot call methods (like `.valueOf`) on it. Check out `Boolean`; note the capital B.

Comment: I'm aware he doesn't want to be calling Boolean.valueOf; but one step at a time. The complaint is syntax errors, and a full answer that fixes all bugs isn't going to teach a solution to the fundamental problem, which is conflating primitive types and classes. I figure once he's getting to different bugs, we'll discuss those; tends to leave a more educated reader.

Comment: it won't even compile after your change, because of <= 18.0 with boolean

Comment: Yep. That's how we do it, one compile error at a time! (I totally agree that your answer is the right one, and have voted you up; I just think it's important to keep the boolean/Boolean discussion visible to the asker.)

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer why this doesn't compile, but you could simply make your life simpler by passing a double directly through your intent.

If you take this value from an `EditText`, parse it as a double in the first activity and that will avoid you to make all this stuff in the second activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(firstActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
i.putExtra("doubleValue", 17.0);
startActivity(i);
```

And then just do:

```
double d = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("doubleValue", 0.0);
```

That will avoid you to parse your `String` as `float` and will simplify your comparisons to a simple `if(d <= 16.0)`, etc.

Comment: sorry it is a double value not float from EditText.

Comment: @user3116603 Then use `getDoubleExtra`.

Comment: @user3116603 `else (Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) > 25.0)` get rid of `(Float.parseFloat(YourBmi) > 25.0)`

Comment: the code is getting complied . thank you !
But the only output i am getting is " You are underweight ".
For all values of bmi whether more than 18 or not the output is same. help pls.!

Comment: @user3116603 Check the value (add a print statement in the log) and you'll see !

Comment: check value where ? Am running the application on my android device. I have created a TextView for giving the value of bmi.
For eg. if value of bmi=19.0 still the review is "You Are Underweight "

Comment: @user3116603 You can write the value to the logcat to see : `Log.w("Value", String.valueOf(d))`

Comment: ok i checkd the value of d before if statement and its 0.0. what to do to change it t the value of bmi ?

Comment: @user3116603 Could you post your updated code ? When you pass this value to your intent in the first activity and when you retrieve it in your second activity.